# SSH using IPV6 getting error "No Route to Host" On My Mac Machine

Tags: terminal, macos, ssh, ipv6

I am trying to **ssh** with **ipv6** in my mac machine but I am getting error **"No Route to Host"**. I can it successfully with ipv4. 
Can anyone guide me please if it require any network setting or else?

I am using OS X 10.10.1 Yosemite.

Thanks!

Comment: Because your ISP is not IPv6-capable?

Comment: might be, Well I am not much aware about networking. With command "lsof -i | grep ssh" I am getting only ipv4 addresses does that mean it's not capable? If so then does it require any changes from network provider or in network configuration. Please suggest.

Comment: `lsof` is irrelevant. You can open Preferences->Network to examine if any of the interface has associated IPv6 address. The most likely reason for lack of IPv6 access is that your ISP providers do not build IPv6 capable networks, and the only recourse is to switch to an IPv6 capable provider, which probably doesn't exist in your region.

Comment: Contact your ISP to find out when they will support IPv6. Everyone in the world must use it soon, but some ISPs are delaying because they don't think their customers care about it.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to perm a route in 10.10 Yosemite. here

You should create a quick script with

"#!/bin/bash"

sudo /sbin/route add -net x.x.x.0/24 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx

save it in a path

chmod a+x the file

Then type this,..

sudo defaults write com.apple.loginwindow LoginHook /Path/To/Your/Script

POW .. Yosemite perm route with edit file .